# asp.net login fails on first and second call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have a login control on an aspx page - mydomain.cloudapp.net/Login.aspx. My login page is running in azure and I have written code for the Page_Load, Login_authenticate and OnLoggedIn routines in login.aspx.vb.

The website has an offline html5 application cache which is checked / refreshed when the page is loaded. I don't think this is affecting the operation of the login. The cache state is 'idle' when I attempt to log in.

My web.config configuration for my membership is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="25" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomizedProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="aspConnectionString" applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="CustomizedProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="25">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomizedProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="aspConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="MyApplication" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

My login control looks like this:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server"
    DestinationPageUrl="~/Users/reports.html" OnAuthenticate="Login_authenticate" OnLoggedIn="OnLoggedIn">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$LoginUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$LoginUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div id="FailText">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-blue min-width input-large LoginButton" ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="ctl00$LoginUser" />
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

I sometimes get a problem where the login fails. Looking at my console and database logs the behaviour seems to be as follows:

1. I open the browser page
2. I enter a username and password
3. I select Login

Result:

No database logs have been added, which indicates that the Page_Load, Login_authenticate and OnLoggedIn routines have not run.

My console log shows that the browser appears to have navigated from mydomain.cloudapp.net to Login.aspx - i.e. console logs that were labelled mydomain.cloudapp.net are now labelled Login.aspx and vice versa

The browser remains on mydomain.cloudapp.net/Login.aspx and shows a blank login box

4. I enter a username and password
5. I select Login

Result:

My database logs show that the user has been logged in. There are logs to show this which were created in my Page_Load, Login_authenticate and OnLoggedIn routines.

My console log shows that the browser appears to have navigated from Login.aspx to mydomain.cloudapp.net - i.e. console logs that were labelled Login.aspx are now labelled mydomain.cloudapp.net and vice versa.

The browser remains on mydomain.cloudapp.net/Login.aspx and shows a blank login box

6. I enter a username and password
7. I select Login

Result: The user is logged in

This behaviour only seems to happen when I first open the page. Once the page is up and running I can log in and out without problems. Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can get users logged in first time?

UPDATE: I've just realised that my database logs don't record any log messages from the Page_Load routine until after Step 5 above. So when I first navigate to the page there is no Page_Load log record and when I first attempt to log in there is no log record, although the console logs indicate that the page has refreshed. Finally, after step 5 Page_Load records a log message, followed by log messages from Login_authenticate and OnLoggedIn. However the user is not redirected to 'reports.html' at this stage, even though the user is now authenticated. It is only after the third login attempt that the user is redirected. My login.aspx.vb routines look like this:

```
    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim sDetails2 As String = ""
        If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            sDetails2 = "User authenticated"
        Else
            sDetails2 = "User not authenticated"
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        End If
        Dim sDetails As String = "Login.aspx - Page_Load"
        Dim iLogType As Integer = WaspWAVB.con.ciLogLogin
        Dim iInspection As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
        Dim iCompany As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
        WaspWAVB.SysUtilities.AddLog(HttpContext.Current.Session, HttpContext.Current.Request, iLogType, sDetails, sDetails2, iInspection, iCompany, Nothing)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Login_authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)

        Dim loginU As Login = Me.FindControl("LoginUser")
        Dim mu As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(loginU.UserName, False)
        If mu IsNot Nothing Then
            If mu.IsLockedOut Then
                If mu.LastLockoutDate.AddMinutes(15) < Now() Then
                    Dim bLockedOut As Boolean = mu.UnlockUser()
                End If
            End If
        End If
        e.Authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(loginU.UserName, loginU.Password)

        If Not e.Authenticated Then
            Dim sDetails As String = "Login.aspx - Login_authenticate"
            Dim sDetails2 As String = "User not authenticated: " & loginU.UserName & " - " & loginU.Password
            Dim iLogType As Integer = WaspWAVB.con.ciLogLogin
            Dim iInspection As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
            Dim iCompany As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
            WaspWAVB.SysUtilities.AddLog(HttpContext.Current.Session, HttpContext.Current.Request, iLogType, sDetails, sDetails2, iInspection, iCompany, Nothing)

        Else
            Dim sDetails As String = "Login.aspx - Login_authenticate"
            Dim sDetails2 As String = "User authenticated: " & loginU.UserName & " - " & loginU.Password
            Dim iLogType As Integer = WaspWAVB.con.ciLogLogin
            Dim iInspection As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
            Dim iCompany As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
            WaspWAVB.SysUtilities.AddLog(HttpContext.Current.Session, HttpContext.Current.Request, iLogType, sDetails, sDetails2, iInspection, iCompany, Nothing)

        End If

    End Sub

    Sub OnLoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim loginU As Login = Me.FindControl("LoginUser")
        Dim pc As WaspWAVB.ProfileCommon = New WaspWAVB.ProfileCommon
        pc.Initialize(loginU.UserName, True)
        Dim iCompany As Int32 = CInt(pc.CompanyID)

        Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(loginU.UserName, False)
        Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)
        Dim newTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, iCompany.ToString)

        authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket)
        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie)

        Dim sDetails As String = "Login.aspx - OnLoggedIn"
        Dim sDetails2 As String = "Logged in:" & loginU.UserName
        Dim iLogType As Integer = WaspWAVB.con.ciLogLogin
        Dim iInspection As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
        WaspWAVB.SysUtilities.AddLog(HttpContext.Current.Session, HttpContext.Current.Request, iLogType, sDetails, sDetails2, iInspection, iCompany, Nothing)

    End Sub
```

Comment: We need to see some code to understand the problem and help you properly. But it seems like there is some issue with you maybe not connecting to the database properly when pressing login the first time.

Comment: Please edit your main post instead of posting in comments.